# How to access the properties of a query result in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can find a document on my database. A call to:

```
subject = await Subject.find({ name: 'Math' });
res.send(subject);
```

returns the document correctly:

```
{
        "topics": [],
        "_id": "5ab71fe102863b28e8fd1a3a",
        "name": "Math",
        "__v": 0
}
```

The problem is when I try to access the properties of `subject`. Any of the following calls returns nothing:

```
res.send(subject._id);
res.send(subject.name);
```

I've tried `subject.toObject()` and `subject.toArray()` but I receive an error:

```
(node:2068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: subject.toObject is not a function
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

NB:
before `res.send(subject)`, I called `console.log(subject)` and the output is:

```
[ { topics: [],
    _id: 5ab71fe102863b28e8fd1a3a,
    name: 'cocei5',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Before sending response try console.log(subject) and post the output here.

Comment: I just edited the post with that information!

Comment: You can try answer which I gave.It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because find method in MongoDB always returns an array.

```
subject = await Subject.find({ name: 'Math' });
```

So in above line the `Subject.find({name: 'Math'})` is returning an array. Which you are storing in subject variable. if you are getting only single object from DB then you might access the object properties by using `subject[0].propertyName`.

like if you want to send just an id you can do it by

```
res.send(subject[0]._id);
```

Comment: One more suggestion if you are sure that you will always get a single result I recommended to use Subject.findOne() instead of SUbject.find(). For better performance.

Comment: I did it! But it seems that my up arrows doesnt count because I have no user reputation here at StackOverFlow :( Thank you again!

Comment: I changed to Subject.findOne()! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the es6 destructuring feature to get the first element returned in the array, as long as you are sure the result will always be on the 0th index.

```
const [subject] = await Subject.find({ name: 'Math' });

res.send(subject._id);
res.send(subject.name);
```

ref: [Destructuring arrays and objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
[Details for find api](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find)

OR you can either use
const subject = await Subject.findOne({ name: 'Math' });

```
res.send(subject._id);
res.send(subject.name);
```

As findOne return object whereas find returns an array of objects.
ref: [Details for findOne api](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne)